# Angular2 Updating view using one-way data binding

Tags: angular, angular-material

If I understood correctly, one-way data binding is from model to view and is achieved using the double curly braces {{}} or square braces [].

I want to update a counter (badge) inside a button. The update is not reflected automatically after the change in the model, is updated after I click on the button. Everything done in the same component.

My code:

.html:

```
<button
mat-raised-button
matStepperNext
[matBadge]="polygonCounter"
matBadgePosition="below"
matBadgeColor="accent">
Next
</button>
```

.ts:

```
polygonCounter: number; //declared

 ngOnInit() {
...
    this.polygonCounter = 0;
...
  }
```

The function that changes the value:

```
onMapDrawed(e): void {
    ....
    this.polygonCounter = 0;
    let counter = 0;
    ...//function that get the new counter
    this.polygonCounter = counter; //counter has the new value
}
```

This also isn't updating in the view, for example:

```
<p>{{polygonCounter}}</p>
```

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure your `onMapDrawed` function is working out as you expect? Can you `console.log(this.polygonCounter);` at the end?

Comment: Thank you @Jeto I did a few tests as you suggested, and yes I can console.log the new counter at the end, but still doesn't always update, sometimes it does. I'm using Asymmetrik's ngx-leaflet and leaflet-draw. Since there is no problem with Angular, maybe is something related with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, when making a change inside of a Leaflet event handler, you need to trigger change detection that is because Leaflet callbacks are running outside of the Angular zone. So what I did is inject the Angular zone reference and then inside my function handler:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
  this.polygonCounter = counter;
});
```

As indicated here: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

It looks like function which gets the new counter is out of ngZone change detection. You can try it with `setTimeout`. It happens specially when third party is involved.

```
onMapDrawed(e): void {
    ....
    this.polygonCounter = 0;
    let counter = 0;
    ...//function that get the new counter
    setTimeout(()=>this.polygonCounter = counter); //change in setTimeout
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. You pointed towards the right direction regarding ngZone and change detection. It was an issue with Leaflet event handler and I needed to trigger change detection.